# NetBIOS access fails unexpectedly at one terminal

Tags: network-share, netbios

I have a share folder on a local machine (same subnet) with IP address *ipaddress*, NetBIOS name server-name, and a DNS A entry of server-name.example.com.  I can reach it normally through

```
nbtstat -A ipaddress
nbtstat -a server-name
ping server-name
ping server-name.example.com
```

but cannot access it at `\\server-name` and

```
net view \\server-name
```

fails.  However, this terminal was able to access the share yesterday (and every day before that for months, at least).  Further, all other computers can access it just fine:

```
C:\Users\owner>net view \\server-name
Shared resources at \\server-name



Share name      Type   Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AdobePDF       Print           Adobe PDF
SharedFolder1  Disk
SharedFolder2  Disk
SharedFolder3  Disk
HPLaserJ.2     Print           HP LaserJet P30xx Series PS
SharedFolder2  Disk
SharedFolder3  Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: Is the Workstation service running on the affected computer? If not, that's the likely cause of the problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Yes, it is.  I don't know of any changes made to the terminal since the share folder was working properly.

Comment: To be clear, this problem is only affecting one client, and the workstation service on that client is running? Have you tried rebooting the client?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Correct, only affecting one client which does have the workstation service running.  The client has been rebooted half a dozen times without fixing the problem (or I wouldn't have bothered you!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved itself about a week after the problem initially occurred.  I still don't know what caused it, but restarting the client and server didn't (immediately) help.